# Safe 0–300 VDC variable supply

Tags: power-supply, transformer, variable

I want to make a 0–300V variable DC power supply (max current 100 mA). I found [this design](http://www.eleccircuit.com/the-variable-high-voltage-power-supply-0-300v/),

[image: variable supply w/ 1:1 120 VAC transformer]

which features a 1:1 transformer across the mains for some sort of safety reasons. However, I couldn't find any 1:1 120 VAC transformers that weren't incredibly expensive. Next I looked at [this circuit](http://www.homemade-circuits.com/2013/06/0-300v-variable-voltage-current.html),

[image: variable supply without a transformer]

which uses a light-bulb "in order to provide ultimate safety in case of a short circuit or a component failure."

I'm not myself able to ascertain if the correct design precautions are being observed in either of these circuits. The second claims to be lethal to the touch.

My question is: does this second circuit exhibit any obvious safety-related flaws in its design (besides, perhaps, contact lethality)? If so, what is the cheapest method of achieving a 0–300V variable power supply while observing all relevant safety considerations, and will any DIY implementation be, to some extent, inherently dangerous?

Comment: What part of "lethal to the touch" doesn't sound safety-related to you?

Comment: @ThePhoton how would this be rectified?

Comment: Use a transformer, like in the first circuit. But there's still a risk if the user touches both terminals at the same time. 300 V is inherently risky.

Comment: @ThePhoton okay, awesome. Are 1:1 120VAC transformers like the one required by that circuit just unavoidably expensive? I guess store-bought high-voltage variable supplies are expensive for a reason...

Comment: What's expensive? I'm not a transformer expert but I see likely candidate parts on Digikey for $20-30. That's a lot more than a 7805, but a lot less than a fancy FPGA.

Comment: If you are relying on a transformer for safety reasons, make sure it has an isolation rating between primary and secondary that you are comfortable with.

Comment: You haven't specified the maximum current you want from your supply. Until you do this, searching for components is a waste of time.

Comment: @replete, both schematics say 100 mA output current.

Comment: @The Photon, the OP has not committed to either schematic and has said nothing about whether that meets his requirements.

Comment: @replete ahhhh, my bad. Maximum current 100 mA (incidentally same as in both circuits)

Comment: @ThePhoton oh, wow. That's great! I must be misunderstanding something in my search—when I select 120 V as the primary and secondary voltages on the DigiKey parts filter menu, it gives 0 results. Could you give me an example transformer part number?

Comment: There's a bunch of different options for primary that include 110. Try multi-clicking all the ones that might work for you. [Here's a "cheap" one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/signal-transformer/A41-25-230/595-1303-ND/953173) but I doubt I know enough to know it's good for your circuit. Also, are you sure your circuit will give 300 V out with 120 Vac in? (Or are you actually looking for a 1:2 transformer?)

Comment: [Here's one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/triad-magnetics/VPS230-190/237-1270-ND/666156) with a bit more margin relative to your power requirement.

Comment: @ThePhoton I'm not sure. I hadn't thought beyond what the design was suggesting. As long as I could still get a variable range from 0 to that 300 V maximum output, freeing myself from the 1:1 transformer constraint would undoubtedly widen my options

Comment: @ThePhoton awesome, thanks! Looks like I'll be trying one of those. I did not until now realize that the common US wall supply varies around a common value and the transformer's primary voltage can be, for example, 115 VAC instead of 120 VAC

Comment: OK, just remember, 300 V / 100 mA is plenty enough to hurt or kill you, so keep one hand in your pocket and make sure you understand what you're doing before you put this thing together.

Comment: @ThePhoton Here's an interesting meta question. My question has been answered. Should I answer it myself, citing the discussion in the comments, or just close it?

Comment: I think it's a worthwhile question for some future reader. Go ahead and post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collected Information from the Comments:

1. The lack of a transformer in the second circuit is prohibitively unsafe, so I'm going with the first schematic.
2. 1:1 transformers like the one used in the first circuit are, in fact, relatively cheap—e.g., [one candidate](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/signal-transformer/A41-25-230/595-1303-ND/953173) for $14 and [another](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/triad-magnetics/VPS230-190/237-1270-ND/666156) for $18.
3. The input voltage for the first circuit is actually 220 VAC—an oversight on my part. However, I can link the output windings of the above transformers in series to achieve my desired output voltage.
4. However, the voltage and current maximums achieved by the circuit are, in fact, just "ball-parks". Since the circuit deals above the benchmark for lethal current, a variable maximum is far from ideal.
5. The lack of a fuse on the primary side would render the first circuit illegal in many places.
6. A 300V 100mA supply is potentially lethal, so don't touch both terminals at the same time. Circuits with dangerously high output voltages shouldn't be built by people who don't know what they're doing (or have only a loose grasp).

Comment: The transformers in your DigiKey links can have their output windings connected in series for your desired output voltage.

Comment: @replete awesome, thanks! I added that to the answer

Comment: Are you following the first schematic, then? It is of course far from a complete design.

Comment: @replete yeah, probably. What would be most important to add to it?

Comment: For starters: this circuit does not limit the output voltage to 300V, it is simply in the ballpark. If you want precision you will need some form of meter. Likewise the current limit is not at all precise, don't be surprised if in practice it allows 150mA. You know best whether this works for you. Also you must consider the thermal design around the MOSFET. It will have to dissipate tens of watts. Also the primary side is wrong and in many localities illegal as there is no fuse.

Comment: @replete ah, okay. I was planning on adding a fuse, but the variability of the current limit is more concerning. How can I implement more rigorous current limiting? As I understand it, this circuit imposes its (rough) maximum via the resistor R2 and transistor Q2. Also, how else is the primary side incorrect?

Comment: That is a significant question in itself and comments won't do. I suggest you ask a separate question based on the first schematic specifically about accurate current limiting. Decide on a margin you find acceptable (10mA either way? 5mA? 20mA?)

Comment: @replete I posted the new question. Also lowered my desired maximum current to 50 mA. 100mA would also work, but 50 mA would be ideal

Comment: However, note that 300 volts times .1 amps is 30 VA. Your first candidate is 25 VA.

Comment: You first candidate transformer is not good for this purpose, 300V@100mA is 30W, which needs more than 30VA to be passed though the transformer, your transformer can only handle 25VA

Answer (score 1):

300V power supply can push current thru the  skin resistance of human fingers thus not really a safe thing in any sense especially when someone accidentally touched both output terminals of this power supply.

To answer your question about 1:1 isolation transformer, if you cannot get one, you can do it by yourself.

For such low current (100mA) output, the easiest way to do this is by connecting two step down transformers back to back. Example, get two 240V to 12V unit with secondary current ratings of 2Amps. Connect the low voltage sides of the transformers so that the second transformer will essentially works as the step up transformer.

Now you should have 240V at the output of the second transformer which is actually isolated from the mains line voltage by in excess of 1000V breakdown ratings.

If the "safe" thing that you mention in your question is about this isolation, than I think it cannot get any "safer" than this..

Good luck.